# c++ typeid on class member operator() overloads

Tags: c++, overloading, pointer-to-member, typeid, typeinfo

When do the following in gcc 4.8.2,

```
class A
{
public:
   void operator()(int);
   void operator()(const std::string&) {}
};

std::cout << typeid(&A::operator()).name() << std::endl;
```

It gives errors:

```
error: address of overloaded function with no contextual type information.
```

It works for other class member operators, such as operator==.  Is that a syntactic error in the typeid() call for A::operator()?

EDITS: sorry, my bad.  The problem occurs when there are multiple overloaded operator()'s.

Comment: Seems to [work for me](http://rextester.com/PFM1036)

Comment: Cannot reproduce with gcc 6.2

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  Edited the question.  It happends when there are multiple overloaded operator() defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [static_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast#Notes) to pick up what you want from overloads.

> `static_cast` may also be used to disambiguate function overloads by performing a function-to-pointer conversion to specific type, as in `std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::toupper));`

e.g.

```
std::cout << typeid(static_cast<void(A::*)(int)>(&A::operator())).name() << std::endl;
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/BJHTPZ24032)